# How do I add more vhosts and users to RabbitMQ without Sudo?

Tags: rabbitmq, travis-ci

Travis-CI wants people to migrate to their new container based system and stop using sudo.  Accorting to their documentation (http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#RabbitMQ), to add more vhosts and users, I just add it to the before_script.  It works great using sudo, but without sudo it doesn't work.

Any ideas how I'm supposed to use their new container based system without sudo, but still add vhosts and users?

My travis.yml script:

```
before_script:
  - sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost "example_testbed"
```

Comment: What problem do you try to solve using non-default vhost?

Comment: if it works, why do you want to avoid this?